# Share a folder from UBUNTU

Tags: samba, shared-folders

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 inside VMware on a Windows 7 host and I need to share a folder to the host machine.  I've successfully shared the folder so it's visible to the Windows side, but I need to be able to have this work on multiple domains for different users.  Any idea on how I can make this folder available to everyone no matter what domain it's running on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using Samba to create a network share. [This](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20(Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal)%20-%20Uncomplicated,%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way!) link should help you get a samba share set up. And [this](https://www.novell.com/communities/coolsolutions/samba-sharing-resources-mulitple-domains/) link should help in allowing multiple domains to use the share. Personally, I've never had to configure Samba for multiple domains, but between these links, and the man pages, you should be able to get a working, elegant, solution.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I was hoping for a universal solution so I don't have to worry about where the VM is run (different customers can run the VM on their network and still be able to access the shared folder without having to make changes to the Linux VM).  Any possibility of doing something like that?

Comment: Just to clarify, you want your customers to be able to actually remote into the VM and access the folder(s)? Because a Samba share mounts as a network drive, meaning that once you set it up, anyone that you give credentials to can access the folder(s). Or are you simply saying that you want the storage to be on the Linux VM, but not managed from the VM itself?

Comment: I want the customers to be able to access a folder on the Linux VM by going to explorer on the windows host side, typing in the ip address of the vm and then see the folder pop up.  Copy files into the folder and then do a build on the Linux side.  Drag and drop into the VM is not reliable and they can not use a thumb drive to copy files over.  So I need a network share.  After I rebooted my PC and left the Domain at the default WORKGROUP, connecting to the share seemed to work.  If   I shutdown the VM, connecting from the windows side seems to fail., but killing the VM is not normal operation

Comment: That's exactly what Samba does. It allows you to access the folder from your machine as long as the VM is powered up. Any files saved to the share will automatically update on the VM. It won't usually use the IP address (though it can). Normally, you'll address the share by connecting to server using \\serverName\share. Then you can use this link (https://help.lafayette.edu/samba/win7nondomain) as a guide to mapping the share so that it shows up like a network hard drive.